# How to check amount in an Authorized.Net test account?

Tags: payment-gateway, authorize.net

I have created an account on authorized.net, and I am testing transaction using direct post method , but I am confused how to check the amount in my account ???

Answer (score 1):

You can [login to the developer control panel](https://test.authorize.net/) which is exactly like a live control panel except no real transactions are processed. When you signed up for the developer account you should have been given a login ID and password. Once logged in you can view your test transactions in there under the "unsettled transactions" link.